# Tic Tac Toe prevent user from going in taken spot

Tags: c

```
int main (void)
{
    char tttarray[3][3] = {
        {'1','2','3'},
        {'4','5','6'},
        {'7','8','9'}
    };


    int turn = 0,i,j,loc;
    char XO;

    while(turn<=9)
    {
        printf("Enter (x) or (o): ");
        scanf("%c",&XO);
        getchar();
        printf("Enter number: ");
        scanf("%d", &loc);

        j = (loc - 1)%3;
        i = (loc - 1)/3;

        if(tttarray[i][j] == 'x' || 'o')
        {
            return(0);
            printf("That spot has been taken!\n");
        }


        tttarray[i][j] = XO;
        printArray(tttarray);

    }

}
```

I'm only showing main the code for convenience. My problem is with this part:

```
if(tttarray[i][j] == 'x' || 'o')
{
    return(0);
    printf("That spot has been taken!\n");
}
```

This is because it always seems to be true which prevents the player from placing an `'x'` or `'o'` there. Am I missing something in the above code? How do prevent the user from going to a taken space?

Comment: what is your code doing right now? isnt return(0) in the main closing your application?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot *chain* the logical OR operator like you did. You need to change

```
 if(tttarray[i][j] == 'x' || 'o')
```

to

```
if((tttarray[i][j] == 'x') || (tttarray[i][j] =='o'))
```

That said, a statement after a `return` statement does not make any sense. Control will *never* reach the `printf()` inside the `if` condition. Maybe what you want is to use

- `printf()` statement
- `continue;`

in this very order.